# Download file from server in ASP.NET? What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I try to use the code below for **downloading a file from the server**.
The controller is called when I click the right button.
The file is exist. The `content` is loaded with bytes.
There is no exception, and the return is called right.

**BUT** the file open/save dialog, or anything is not triggered. Nothing happens...
What can be the problem with that code?

```
public FileContentResult Export()
    {
        byte[] contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/") + "Data.PNG");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Data.PNG");
        return File(contents, "application/octetstream");
    }
```

Comment: Are you using ajaxpanel or something like that? I yes, i think you have to remove it.

Comment: Oh man, add it as an answer andI accept it! :) I Use @using (Ajax.BeginForm ...

Comment: I hope i helped you. I have faced the same problem in the past and i could not find the answer.

Comment: Yes, you helped ;)! I had to change the Ajax.beginform to HTML.beginform, and it works immedietly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ajaxpanel or something like tha i think you have to remove it.